# Not receiving message for subcribed topic from Azure IoT MQTT broker

Tags: azure, mqtt, iot, azure-iot-hub

Please, help me to resolve this issue, I have tried all the options...
i used `MqttClient` client to subcribed iot hub mqtt broker using topic

```
devices/t2c-171bdd65-407d-4de9-992b-36cee0914b3f/messages/devicebound/#
```

but I wasn't able to receive any callback...
I am  running this application from my local machine and connecting to Azure IoT hub MQTT broker. well, I am able to publish message to IoT hub, I can confirm this because IoT hub message count is increasing & device explorer running on my local machine is displaying message in monitor mode.

Comment: This type of question is suitable for ServerFault forum of stack exchange, you can post your question there. StackOverflow is mainly for programming related questions. If you think your question is programming related, please post some code snippets too.

Comment: It would be easier to troubleshoot your problem with some code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm supposing you're using M2MQTT nuget package for MQTT client.

I have some sample code that proves working on my local PC and my Azure IoT Hub. You can find it in https://github.com/ghjackie/AzureIoTDemo

You need to follow the tutorial from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-mqtt-support/) to modify the deviceId, hostName, etc...